# Number pipe number : '1.2-2' is not working while using by a ternary inside *ngFor directives

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular12

I was working on a project using Angular 12. At some stage, I needed to render an array of objects which I got from the API. In each object, I have some fields of numbers like CostPrice, TradePrice, MRP, SellingPrice.

My target is to render those and view those inside the input tag. I have a variable named `forViewDetails`, based on which I was trying to make the field read-only. Inside the value attribute, I have binded the fields using attribute binding. There I was rendering the prices based on the `forViewDetails` option. If it is true then the values will appear with two decimal points. That's why I have used the number pipe inside a bracket. Else it will appear without points.

But the thing is it's working for CostPrice and TradePrice. But for MRP and TradePrice it's not working. If I remove the pipe from them, then it works. But after adding pipe the fields become empty. I thought maybe I am not getting the number in those fields. But I checked those, those were numbers.

I am attaching the code samples below. Any solution or suggestion is highly appreciated.

The output I am getting using pipe:

[image]

The output after removing the pipe from `MRP`:

[image]

```
<!-- trade price -->
<td style="width: 100px">
  <input
    [readonly]="forViewDetails"
    id="itemTp_{{ i }}"
    type="number"
    min="0"
    class="form-control w-100"
    [value]="forViewDetails ? (item.TradePrice | number : '1.2-2') : item.TradePrice"
    (input)="tpChanged(i, item, $event)"
    (keyup.enter)="nextInput('tp', $event)"
    [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && item.TradePrice == 0 }" />
</td>



<!-- mrp -->   
<td style="width: 100px">
  <input
    [readonly]="forViewDetails"
    id="itemMrp_{{ i }}"
    type="number"
    min="0"
    class="form-control w-100"
    [value]="forViewDetails ? (item.MRP | number : '1.2-2') : item.MRP"
    (input)="mrpChanged(i, item, $event)"
    (keyup.enter)="nextInput('mrp', $event)"
    [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && item.MRP == 0 }" />
</td>
```

```
//object I am getting
{
    Barcode: "B-090807",
    BrandId: "BRD00002",
    CategoryId: "SUBCAT0100",
    CompanyId: "COM00002",
    CostPrice: 900,
    Discount: 0,
    ExpDate: "2050-05-14",
    Id: 8,
    MRP: 1200,
    MinShelfLife: 9999,
    PVAT: 0,
    ProductGrossWeight: 0,
    ProductId: "PRD1671704018388",
    ProductMargin: 0,
    ProductName: "Hilsha Fish",
    ProductNetWeight: 0,
    ProductQty: 50,
    ProductUnit: "kg",
    SellingPrice: 1200,
    StockReceivedId: "SR-1672203680930",
    SupplierId: "SUP00002",
    TAX: 0,
    TradePrice: 900,
    VAT: 0,
}
```

My target is to achieve all values in decimal form with two fraction points after it as I am getting in CostPrice and TradePrice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it is not showing is due to the `MRP` value exceeding a thousand, with the `Number` pipe will display as "1,000.00" (with thousand separator), and the `<input type="number" />` doesn't allow for the comma character.

In order to solve it, you should do either of these:

1. Not apply the `number` pipe to format the value in `<input type="number" />`
2. Implement a custom pipe to remove the comma character.

```
<input
  [value]="forViewDetails ? (item.MRP | number: '1.2-2' | noComma) : item.MRP"
/>
```

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'noComma' })
export class NoCommaPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, ...args: any[]) {
    return value.toString().replace(/,/g, '');
  }
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v3hs5w?file=src/app/app.component.html)

3. Use `<input type="text" />` instead to allow displaying the formatted number with thousand separator.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found that number pipe returns string or null. But still confused that as it is returning string why its allowing before 1000! may be it is converting when comma become added. I needed both comma and decimal points. So have just bounded the type attribute according to the forViewDetails. If its true then type will be text. Otherwise number. But your explanation was the real hero. Thank you very much for your time and effort.